# what is the property management.health.redis.enabled and how to use it?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, redis

Am seeing this property in one of our application.yml , what is this property and it has value true , what does that mean ? and how to use it if it has value true ?

Answer (score 11):

It indicates the enability of Redis health check.

```
management.health.redis.enabled=true # Whether to enable Redis health check.
```

Here true indicates that redis health check is enabled and false indicates not enabled.

Use is very simple just put `management.health.redis.enabled` to true if you want to enable redis health check and false for disable.

See this : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties

Comment: what will happen if we enable ? how to check redis health if we enable ? if their end point ?

Comment: to check redis health by accessing the url localhost:8080/health you will get this response and in that redis also present {"status":"UP","diskSpace":{"status":"UP","total":499046809600,"free":266940710912,"threshold":10485760},"redis":{"status":"UP"}}